# FireMonkey XE5 Icons for iOS app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have an iOS app developed in FireMonkey XE5 (Update 2) and I have set up all the application icons for the iPad (as found under project options).  When running on an actual device, **the spotlight search icon always uses the default FireMonkey icon**.

I have looked the the deployment options and removed the default icons, but they are been added automatically.

I have added spotlight images for the iPhone settings (even though I am running this on an iPad), but this did not help.

I have replaced the default spotlight images in the bin/Artwork folders with my images and this did not help.  I guess if I replace ALL default images in iPad + iPhone folders I will solve my problem, but this will not work if I am developing a second application.

Has anyone experienced this problem with Delphi FireMonkey applications?  Any suggestions on what will work to solve this for all projects?

Comment: This info (from the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Application_Options) - see *Notes for iOS*) might help: If you do not want to provide a specific image, clear the image field, and click OK. **If you clear an image field, make sure the selected Target on the Application page is All configurations. Empty fields are filled with the paths in parent targets, and All configurations is the only target that does not get overwritten.** This might explain why you remove them and they're re-added automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this. The thing is I do want to provide all the images and have created all the necessary files. FireMonkey however still includes some of it's own default images

Comment: Did you check if you added it for the right configuration(Debug or release) and also for simulator or device?

Comment: I did check thanks. Most of the images work as set up, it is just the Spotlight Search images that are not being replaced.